# XAMPP Access forbidden! for Symbolic Link on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: php, linux, xampp, symlink, ubuntu-22.04

I'm trying to Access my PHP files located in

```
/home/USERNAME/Documents/PROJECT_FOLDER
```

through a symbolic link in

```
 /opt/lampp/htdocs/
```

but I'm getting an error:

```
Access forbidden!
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403
localhost
Apache/2.4.53 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1o PHP/7.4.29 mod_perl/2.0.12 Perl/v5.34.1
```

I already tried setting permissons with:

```
sudo chmod -R 0777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/SYMBOLIC_LINK
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well. I found the solution to be creating a hard link instead. i.e sudo /home/USERNAME/Documents/PROJECT_FOLDER  /opt/lampp/htdocs/.

Comment: sadly under Ubuntu 22.04 it is not allowed to create hard links.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).